# Jackson Json parse error

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

Hi I am  working on some legacy code and the structure of the JSON model has changed a bit
original Model

```
{
"values": {
    "business": {
        "default": 5.2
    },
    "personal": {
        "charity": 0.728,
        "medical": 1.222,
        "moving": 1.222
    }
}
}
```

The new Model is  something like this

```
{
"_values": {
    "business": {
        "purpose": {
            "default": 5.2
        },
        "vehicle": {
            "automobile": 0.0,
            "bicycle": 0.0,
            "motorcycle": 0.0
        }
    },
    "personal": {
        "purpose": {
            "charity": 0.7280000000000001,
            "medical": 1.222,
            "moving": 1.222
        }
    }
}
}
```

So we are using fasterxml.jackson which I am very new to,  and after a few trying different method i keep getting the error message

**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of double out of START_OBJECT token
                     at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@6b8b2b1; line: 42, column: 11] (through reference chain: >service.api.types.Drive_Json["_values"]->service.api.types.PotentialValues["business"]->java.util.HashMap["purpose"])**

I use the following annotation to extract the mapping  in my Json file

```
@JsonProperty("values")
private values values;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class values {
    public HashMap<String, Double> purpose;
    public HashMap<String, Double> personal;
}
```

The current  existing values  file has two hashmap to hold the values for "personal" & "business"  and  with no explict binding take the model and  stores in respective hashmap.

I changed the JsonProperty field in my json file as "_value" and tried changing the values class file but i keep getting  the mapping error can anybody please help in me  creating the correct model for value class.
I tried hashmap  one each of but  not sure how do i map them.

```
@JsonProperty("_values") 
private values Values; 

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class values {
public HashMap<String, Double> business_purpose;
public HashMap<String, Double> business_vehicle;
public HashMap<String, Double> personal_purpose;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different approaches you can follow to parse your JSON into Java objects. Find below two of them (but mind there are many others you could consider):

### Approach 1

You should use `@JsonProperty("_values")` instead of `@JsonProperty("values")` to match your new JSON. So your model classes will be as following:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Values {

    private Map<String, Object> business;
    private Map<String, Object> personal;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

```java
public class Data {

    @JsonProperty("_values")
    private Values values;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

To parse it, you could use:

```java
String json = "{\"_values\":{\"business\":{\"purpose\":{\"default\":5.2},\"vehicle\":"
            + "{\"automobile\":0.0,\"bicycle\":0.0,\"motorcycle\":0.0}},\"personal\":"
            + "{\"purpose\":{\"charity\":0.728,\"medical\":1.222,\"moving\":1.222}}}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Data data = mapper.readValue(json, Data.class);
```

### Approach 2

Alternativelly, you could parse your JSON string into a `Map<String, Object>`. It could be achieved with the following lines:

```java
String json = "{\"_values\":{\"business\":{\"purpose\":{\"default\":5.2},\"vehicle\":"
            + "{\"automobile\":0.0,\"bicycle\":0.0,\"motorcycle\":0.0}},\"personal\":"
            + "{\"purpose\":{\"charity\":0.728,\"medical\":1.222,\"moving\":1.222}}}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> values = mapper.readValue(json, 
                                    new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {});
```

Comment: hi  yes i am doing that  thats  why the mapping into hasmap seem to fails , i mentioned it my post above

Comment: @amIT The JSON you provided in your question is not valid. Try http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: opps  my mistake   skippe the brackets  while  posting here , the json  are valid , let  me add the braces.

Comment: @amIT Please ensure you provide accurate pieces of code when asking a question.

Comment: made the changes  can you suggest how i make this work ?

Answer (score -1):

To send the response as String use annotiaon to java property in java pojo .
example : 
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
protected Long userId;